# Concepto "Este objeto parece un vector 3D"

Tags: c++, conceptos

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto que contiene varias librerías en que cada una de ellas define algún tipo de [Vector](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector) 3D. Por ejemplo, uso el [vector de SFML](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Vector3.php) en unas partes del código y el, [vector de reactphysics3d](https://www.reactphysics3d.com/usermanual.html) en otras, y otro vector 3D de otra librería en otras partes.

Me veo en la necesidad de programar el producto vectorial y el operador de salida por consola (`std::ostream &operator <<`) para cada uno de los vectores:

```
constexpr sf::Vector3f cross(const sf::Vector3f &a, const sf::Vector3f &b)
{
    return { a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}

std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const sf::Vector3f &v)
{
    return o << '{' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << '}';
}

// ... repetir por cada tipo de vector 3D...
```

Lo que implica mucha repetición de código así que he intentado una solución con plantillas:

```
template <typename vector3a_t, typename vector3b_t>
constexpr vector3a_t cross(const vector3a_t &a, const vector3b_t &b)
{
    return { a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}
```

En el código anterior, la plantilla recibe dos tipos arbitrarios que espera que contengan los miembros `x`, `y` y `z` y que al menos el primer tipo sea construible mediante el resultado de operaciones aritméticas de cada uno de los miembros; pero esta solución obviamente no funciona para el operador de salida por consola:

```
template <typename vector3_t>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const vector3_t &v)
{
    return o << '{' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << '}';
}
```

En la función anterior, el tipo `vector3_t` puede ser cualquier cosa lo cuál provoca múltiples ambigüedades al compilar, así que me preguntaba si sería posible restringir ese tipo para que sea "*algo que se parezca a un vector 3D*", he intentado lo siguiente:

```
template <typename vector_t>
concept vector3_c = requires(vector_t v) { // error: expected unqualified-id
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.x)> } -> true;
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.y)> } -> true;
    { std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.z)> } -> true;
};

template <vector3_c A, vector3_c B>
constexpr A cross(const A &a, const B &b)
{
    return { a.y * b.z - a.z * b.y, a.z * b.x - a.x * b.z, a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x};
}

template <vector3_c V>
std::ostream &operator <<(std::ostream &o, const V &v)
{
    return o << '{' << v.x << ", " << v.y << ", " << v.z << '}';
}
```

Pero no compila. Es la primera vez que intento implementar conceptos y no se si lo que intento hacer es posible.

Answer (score 2):

Una forma en la que puedes hacer lo que buscas es utilizando [requisitos anidados](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constraints#Nested_requirements). Estos sirven para dar requisitos nuevos en términos de los parámetros locales.

El concepto pasaría a ser:

```cpp
template <typename vector_t>
concept vector3_c = requires (vector_t v){
    requires std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.x)>;
    requires std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.y)>;
    requires std::is_scalar_v<decltype(v.z)>;
};
```

[Test en godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/EG5s7W8WK).